# Linqpad & EF5 Code First

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, linqpad

Getting the following error when trying to run a query against a dbcontext assembly in Linqpad.

> InvalidOperationException: The model backing the 'UserQuery' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

Having done a bit of reading it seems that:

```
Database.SetInitializer<DiaryAssistantContext>(null);
```

is needed. However this is already in my derived DbContext class.

Can anybody give me a pointer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While an answer has already been accepted, in my case I wanted a solution that was a little more compile-time friendly. The following solution is similar to the example in the accepted answer that uses reflection, but will provide a little extra compile-time checking:

```
Expression<Action> setInitializerExpression = () => Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
var setInitializerCall = (MethodCallExpression) setInitializerExpression.Body;
var setInitializerMethodInfo =
    setInitializerCall.Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition().MakeGenericMethod(GetType());
setInitializerMethodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] {null});
```

Answer (score 10):

LINQPad subclasses your typed data context so you can run queries without referencing the instance. Maybe the SetInitializer method needs the subclassed type.

What happens if you replace this code:

```
Database.SetInitializer<DiaryAssistantContext>(null);
```

with this:

```
typeof (Database).GetMethod ("SetInitializer").MakeGenericMethod (GetType()).Invoke (null, new object[] { null });
```

?

Comment: I have added your suggested line to the constructor of the dbcontext derived class and it works perfectly. I'm not sure fully understand why though.

Comment: GetType() is virtual, so it's equivalent to calling Database.SetInitializer<UserQuery>(null); when run in LINQPad